# MySQL - importing from csv File with some columns without columns headers

Tags: mysql

I seek some advice and help. I have almost 1TG of data to import into my MySQL database. I want to use the simplest way to import. Also some of the the columns does not have a header, and how do I ignore those columns and not import them. Only import those that has column header. Also I want to be able to create the table as I import. I have almost 50 tables to create. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. I have MySQL workbench installed

---

Comment: how can you find which Column does not have a header. You can use the cut tool like: cut -d',' -f1-13 filename > newfile - to copy only field 1 to 13 and the fields are separeted by ',' . also you can specify each column like: cut -D',' -f1,4,7,9-12 ....

Comment: each excel csv is 15GB and more, I am not able to open to manipulate it. that is my hurdle.

Comment: What is an excel csv and how does it differ from a normal csv? And to answer your question, the tool of choice would be [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). You can create the table by e.g. the code by John Swapceinski posted on the linked site or by hand, and you will still have to do some things manually (e.g. checking which files/columns have headers, entering the commands, maybe creating the tables, ...), there is no tool that will solve all your specific problems all by itself.

Comment: You can use the split command to split the file in pieces say 1GB to handle it